# Google maps api geocoding limits

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google maps free API provides with 2500 geocoding per day.

Does the limits apply based only client on IP or website on which the javascript is called?

Since the request is JSONP, therefore request comes from the user, so if limits are based on IP, then i should be clear, regardless of how many requests are made..

But still, i'm afraid google does some hocus-pocus..

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your usage of the Google Maps API is limited per site domain, not by API key (since API keys are purely optional). Even if you're not using an API key, your usage is restricted by site, which is reported when you make your requests to Google.

I don't know exactly what Google's rules are, but I'd guess the 2500 limit is per second-level domain (e.g., `example.com` and all its subdomains share a pool of 2500 requests per day).

Comment: Alright, that's exactly what i wanted to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API limits you based on your API key. You provide the API key when you load the javascript files

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE"
```

Comment: No, i can just use:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Estonia&sensor=true

There's no api key..